# Make two cells in same row of 2 tables have same width

Tags: html, css

I have 2 tables in same row of the big table, like this:

```html
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Storage 1</td>
            <td>Storage 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Type A</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Type B</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>10%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>90%</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>40%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>60%</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
```

But when the text in first column (e.g. "Type A") is too long, it makes a new line. Then data in same row is not in same row. ("Type B" is not in same row with "90%" and "60%")

Return data is in xml format, like this:

```
<DataGroup Storage="Storage 1">
    <DataRow Type="Type A" Percentage="10%"/>
    <DataRow Type="Type B" Percentage="90%"/>
</DataGroup>
<DataGroup Storage="Storage 2">
    <DataRow Type="Type A" Percentage="40%"/>
    <DataRow Type="Type B" Percentage="60%"/>
</DataGroup>
```

I have to draw borders to make it look like one table. Render in cshtml file.

How can I resolve this? Many thanks.

Comment: Why you need nested table for simple 3 columns table?

Comment: have you tried setting a hard limit on the size of the first column. and using: `overflow: hidden;` ?

Comment: Because, return data is in xml format. I used foreach in cshtml to render it.

Comment: [whitespace: nonwrap;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `border: 1px solid black;` to CSS to make it like a table. For HTML, you just need one `table`.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Storage 1</td>
    <td>Storage 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Type A
      <br>new line</td>
    <td>10%</td>
    <td>40%</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Type B</td>
    <td>90%</td>
    <td>60%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop word-wrap with `white-space: nowrap;` although it stops honoring the width element.

```css
tr td:nth-child(1){
  width:20px;
  color:red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <td>Type</td>
   <td>Storage 1</td>
   <td>Storage 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Type A</td>
   <td>10%</td>
   <td>40%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Type B</td>
   <td>90%</td>
   <td>60%</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you have a good reason for having tables within table. Then your problem is your semantics. You are not outputting the 'Type B', '90%' and '60%' on the same rows of the big table. Your sub-tables can either be aligned by `vertical-align` as blocks or you need to rework your big table semantics to something like this.

```
 <table class="big">
    <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Storage 1</td>
        <td>Storage 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="small">
                <tr>
                    <td>Type A Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="small">
                <tr>
                    <td>10%</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="small">
                <tr>
                    <td>40%</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="small">
                <tr>
                    <td>Type B</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="small">
                <tr>
                    <td>90%</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="small">
                <tr>
                    <td>60%</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>          
    </tr>
<table>
```